# Loop skipping over a record in Mongo database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I've come across a very peculiar bug.

I have a database with the following records:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "name": "Name1",
    "number": 42
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "name": "Name2",
    "number": 123
}
```

In my javascript code, I have the following code:

```
MyRecords.find({}, function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error finding phone recipients:", err);
    } else if (results.length == 0) {
        console.log("No users");
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var result = results[i];

            someFunction2("", result);

            someFunction1(function(message) {
                someFunction2(message, result);
            });

            result.number = "Some new value"
            result.save(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Error updating last sent for", result.name);
                } else {
                    console.log("Updated last sent time for user:", result.name);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Assume that `someFunction1` and `someFunction2` make some API calls and wait for results for a few milliseconds.

When I run this, the console prints out:

`Updated last sent time for user: Name2`

The user Name1 is not processed. What is going on here?

Comment: *" Assume... make some API calls and wait for results.."* - Unfortunately I cannot "assume" that because that is **not what happens**. These calls are very likely "async", and as such they do not "wait" at all. Execution in the loop continues regardless of whether that result has returned or not unless you handle the execution in such a way that it does. Your "problem" strongly suggests you have not. So rather than asking us to "assume", I advise you actually show what those functions are "really doing". The `save()` here alone will not "pause" on each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Assume that someFunction1 and someFunction2 make some API calls and wait for results for a few milliseconds.

Hi, and there is exactly your problem. Once someFunction2 and someFunction1 have retrieved the data from the API, the loop has already run and the value of 'result' will be the last one in the loop.

A way to avoid this is to abstract those to a function outside of the loop, which receives 'result' as a parameter like so:

```js
MyRecords.find({}, function(err, results) {
 
 function processResult(result) {
  someFunction2("", result);
  someFunction1(function(message) {
   someFunction2(message, result);
  });
  result.number = "Some new value"
  result.save(function(err) {
   if (err) {
    console.log("Error updating last sent for", result.name);
   } else {
    console.log("Updated last sent time for user:", result.name);
   }
  });
 }
 
 if (err) {
  console.log("Error finding phone recipients:", err);
 } else if (results.length == 0) {
  console.log("No users");
 } else {
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
   processResult(results[i]);
  }
 }
}
```

Hope it helps